# How to deploy a React App on Firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

How to deploy a React App on Firebase hosting. When I use firebase init, it creates a "public" page and an "index.html" file but nothing appears when accessing the page after deployment. I put all the folders in "public" and fired firebase deploy, but it still didn't work.

[image]

Comment: You need to  "build" your React project, typically via `npm run build` but check your package.json's "scripts" section to see that you have a "build" script.  As @Uéslei says: you want to deploy the output of the "build" process, not your React's source code.

Answer (score 1):

When firebase asks you which folder you want to use, don't use public, but build.

> What do you want to use as your public directory? **build**

> Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? **Yes**

Reference: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-firebase/